# Remapped Caps-Lock Keybindings stop working on Ubuntu 22.04 with Wayland

Tags: keyboard, 22.04, wayland, emacs, capslock

I am experiencing a peculiar problem on my Ubuntu 22 system running under Wayland. I have remapped the Caps-lock key to function as an additional Control key using the following script:

```
remap_caps() {
  local filename="/etc/default/keyboard"
  local search
  local replace
  if grep XKBOPTIONS= $filename; then
    search=$(grep XKBOPTIONS= $filename)
    replace=XKBOPTIONS="\"ctrl:nocaps,grp:toggle\""
    sudo sed -i "s/$search/$replace/" $filename
  else
    echo XKBOPTIONS="\"ctrl:nocaps,grp:toggle\"" | sudo tee -a $filename
  fi
  if [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "x11" ] || [ "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" = "xwayland" ]; then
    setxkbmap -option 'ctrl:nocaps,grp:toggle'
  fi
  sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
}
```

I also enabled Emacs key theme in GTK settings:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-key-theme "Emacs"
```

Sometimes, predominantly in Emacs and Google Chrome, some key bindings (that use the <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd>) stop working. Most often, this happens with yanking text - <kbd>Caps</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> (while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> still works as expected and yanks text) and next line - <kbd>Caps</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> (while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>n</kbd> still works).

What’s peculiar is that if the Caps or <kbd>y</kbd> keys didn’t work, they would also not work individually. But they do - the <kbd>y</kbd> key still types `y` and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> yanks text as expected. This leads me to believe that while the <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> key is recognized, it is somehow being misinterpreted by the system.

Also noteworthy is that <kbd>Caps</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> function perfectly, as do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd>. To me, this indicates a problem distinctly linked to specific keybindings and not a general failure of the <kbd>Caps-lock</kbd> key.

I suspect the issue might be linked to the GTK settings related to the Emacs key theme that I have applied on my system.

It feels like something on my system is interfering with the GTK shortcuts in Emacs and Chrome from functioning correctly. If anyone has encountered a similar issue or has insights on how I should proceed to debug this, I could use your help.